# Conectar carousel de Bootstrap con base de datos en VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap, vb.net

Estoy intentando enlazar una base de datos con un carrusel de Bootstrap. El código del carrusel que estoy usando es el básico, el que está en la [página de documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).

Hasta el momento sólo he podido ejecutar el carrusel con imágenes que tengo en una carpeta pero no he sabido cómo hacerlo con rutas de imagen que se guardan en la base de datos.

Éste es el código:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="section-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300/people" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Ofertas Fónix</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300/abstract" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Ofertas Fónix</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300/nature" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Ofertas Fónix</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hola @Drago25, por favor muestranos el código que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: El código que muestras es el del ejemplo de Bootstrap. Sería útil si incluyeras algo del código VB.NET que hayas intentado (p.e.: conexión a la bd, consulta, etc)

Comment: La pregunta esta incompleta. Faltan elementos para contestarla.

Comment: Tienes un ***AspNet Repeater*** en tú código ? Una List de entidades como ***DataSource*** ?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes definir un literal (ASPnet Literal) y construir un string con el código HTML

```html
         <div class="item">
                                   <img src="LaRutaDeMiImagen" />
                                   <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h2>El Titulo</h2>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
```

Dicho objeto debe estar dentro de un for o un foreach, el cual se guiará de la sentencia SQL que te devolverá la lista de imágenes. Por cierto, lo único que te recomiendo que hagas es que dentro del carousel, definas la primera imagen, es decir, primero manualmente pones la imagen como tienes en el código mostrado y a partir de la segunda el literal (repetitivo).

Answer (score 0):

Si las imagene estan en la db vas a tener que crear un handler que devuelva en el `Response` el array de byte del archivo que tienes en el campo de la tabla.

aqui

[[ASP.NET] - Guardar Imagen base de datos](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/03/aspnet-guardar-imagen-base-de-datos.html)

Explico como podrias hacerlo, si analizas el artículo veras que el handler se
programa

```
Imagenes imagen = ImagenesDAL.GetImagenById(id);

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", imagen.Nombre));

context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(imagen.Imagen);
context.Response.End();
```

Esa es la parte clave donde pones en el request el archvio que obtienes desde una query

En el carousel usarias

```
<img src="~/Download.ashx?id=1" />
```

Por supuesto lo que importa es la extension `.ashx` y definirle cual es el id o codigo de la imagen en la tabla para poder recuperarla